# Gridlines like in google calendar

Tags: html, css, google-calendar-api

I've been looking and looking but I can't see how google calendar draws those horisontal gridlines in day-view.
It should be simple to figure out with the browsers developer tools, but nope..

I cant spot how they do it. Can anybody clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There it is.
It seems that there is actually a row before the calendar row. This row is 1px high but contains an absolute positioned div so it'll be visible anyway.